# Writing if else condition function in inline code doesn't return any value

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, conditional-operator

Why does this method doesn't return any value?

```
<span>{()=>{
    if(profile.age){
        return (2021 - profile.age)
    }
}}</span>
```

Aren't this the same as when you create a different function and call it like this?

```
<span>{renderAge()}</span>

function renderAge(){
    if(profile.age){
        return (2021 - profile.age)
    }
}
```

I know I can do the inline condition using `? :` but if I have multiple conditions it would be hard and also I don't want to create a separate function for that.

Comment: The first example creates a new function but doesn't call it.

Comment: @Andy so how should I call it from there? any example, if you don't mind.

Comment: Why you wanna do the logic inside the HTML tags? why not create the function outside like your second example?

Comment: It's a very small if else logic like two or three conditions and also to avoid additional lines of codes in my file.

Comment: Are you using a library like React?

Comment: Yes I'm using reactjs

Comment: @Emerald ... One does not want to sacrifice readability in favor of less lines of code, especially not since the readable development code is anyhow transpiled and minified by a build process before getting shipped to production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know react, but i tried to find a possible solution anyway. I can't give you many explanations (I know it's not very professional, but I spent some time on it and I answer anyway).

[This is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/k71rycwh/)

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World! { 
        function(){ 
          if(1==1) {
            return 2021;
          } else {
            return 2022;
          }
        }() 
      } </h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('test'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a function for this, a ternary expression would do just fine:

```
<span>{profile.age ? 2021 - profile.age : ''}</span>
```

But assuming you needed a function, you could use an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), note the extra parenthesis for calling the function in-place:

```
<span>{(() => {
    if (profile.age){
        return (2021 - profile.age);
    }
})()}</span>
```

or, more readable

```
<span>{((age) => {
    if (age) return 2021 - age;
})(profile.age)}</span>
```

which is semantically equivalent to

```
// somewhere earlier
const renderAge = (age) => {
    if (age) return 2021 - age;
};

// and then
<span>{ renderAge(profile.age) }</span>
```